# Rails: get name of called rake task in environment.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-plugins, autoload

i tried to disable autoloading of plugins in my **environment.rb** for the rake task "**gems:install**", since it may lead to unresolved dependencies and errors (read http://blog.joopp.com/2009/01/26/plugin-gem-dependencies-in-your-environmentrb/ for further information).

While implementing this "hack", i quickly noticed that the variable **$rails_gem_installer**, which should be set to true if gems:install is run, **is not set**. (==nil)

Now i'm looking for a way to get information about the called rake task, or is there any other working solution?

Im running Rails 2.3.10 / Ruby 1.8.7

Here's the code from my environment.rb for better understanding:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|

# fix for plugins dependent on gems
# see http://blog.joopp.com/2009/01/26/plugin-gem-dependencies-in-your-environmentrb/ 

if $rails_gem_installer
 # We stop the initializer to load the files from the /config/initializers dir. This is to disable the usage of plugins or gems in that code.
 puts 'Disabling the application initializers (rails_gem_installer == true)'
 class Rails::Initializer
   def load_application_initializers; end
 end

 # Next, do _only_ load the needed plugins that are not dependent on gems. For example exception_notification since that one is used in application.rb.
 puts 'Not loading all plugins (rails_gem_installer == true)'
 config.plugins = [:exception_notification]
else
 # Otherwise, when we're just loading the environment.. load everything in the right order. So this is YOUR config.plugins = [something]!
 config.plugins = [:all]
end

[... stuff like config.gem and so on]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. But if you need to hack default Rails behaviour like this, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: If you ever have been in a situation where a plugin (vendor/plugins) depended on a gem you might understand the issue and why i need that workaround to deploy with capistrano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going down the road of getting `rake gems:install` to work properly, which was something that never seemed to work properly in every situation, it might be better to port your dependencies to [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) instead. Although this is how Rails 3 is configured by default, it can be used on any ruby project and does a much better job.

A `Gemfile` also serves as a human-readable manifest of dependencies, something that's not always easily extracted from a Rails configuration file.

There's an example on using bundler with Rails 2.3 on their site: http://gembundler.com/rails23.html

Comment: Thanks - we're defining our migration path to Rails 3 atm and maybe we should move to Bundler as a first step...

Comment: We now successfully moved to Bundler :) Thanks again for this push in the right direction